# How to obtain email address in X509 Certificate programmatically?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I'm trying to get both the CN and emailAddress field from a X509 cert object in C. Currently i'm getting the CN like this:

```
cert_entry = X509_NAME_get_entry(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0);
ASN1_STRING *entryData = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data( cert_entry );
ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&CN, entryData);
printf("%s",CN);
```

My question is how do I get the emailAddress field? I thought about parsing the string, but I'm guess there has to be a smarter way of doing that?

Comment: Figured it out

    cert_entry = X509_NAME_get_entry(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 5);
    ASN1_STRING *entryData1 = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data( cert_entry );
    ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&email, entryData1);

Each name entry is one entry in the cert, with 0 being country, 1 being state etc...

5 is emailAdress

Comment: Add that as an answer then :)  It's OK to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out

```
X509_NAME * subject_name = X509_get_subject_name(cert); 
int nid_email = OBJ_txt2nid("emailAddress"); 
X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(subject_name, nid_email, peer_email, 256);
```

Comment: There's a guarantee that the email address is index 5? I thought that you would iterate over the collection and see which is an email address (with `X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_object`, if I've read the docs right).

Comment: With some help from my friend I was able to fix the hard code by:
    `X509_NAME * subject_name = X509_get_subject_name(cert);
    int nid_email = OBJ_txt2nid("emailAddress");
    X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(subject_name, nid_email, peer_email, 256);`

Comment: You can also just use constant `NID_pkcs9_emailAddress` for the `NID`.